# jQuery Fancybox iPad and iPhone gallery issues

Tags: jquery, iphone, fancybox, tablet

I'm using jQuery Fancybox plugin for a responsive website. First version of Fancybox has a lot of issues with iPad and iPhones.

I decided to use Fancybox 2 to get an easy fix however this caused a different problem.

If I'm using a gallery which once Fancybox lightbox opens and after going through few images in the gallery (using next and previous buttons once fancybox opens) next & previous buttons along with the close button is not visible anymore.

Also image becomes transparent you can't close the fancybox nor go to another image. You will have to refresh the page to make it work again.

I don't own an iPad or an iPhone. I asked my friends to test it and all had the same issue. However when I try on android tablet or android phone everything works as expected.

I was wondering if anyone had the same problem and if someone was able to fix this irritating iOS problem?

**CODE**

```
$('a[rel^=gallery_]').fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    },
    afterLoad : function() {
        this.title = (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
    }
});
```

Comment: so, where is your code? any link to test? do you want us to guess or look at our magic ball? ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, SOF was read only sometime ago. Well I'm not using anything extra. just normal regular fancybox instantiation. I solved the problem without using Fancybox. However this will come really handy if the problem can be solved. I have added the code.